# Skipping Effects does not work for Array of dynamic URL's

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React.SFC / react stateless / functional component which is unfortunately rendering a little too frequent due to some excess data coming in from redux in a parent component. Nothing I can do about that for now, so I'm just accepting the extra rerenders, and using useEffect to make sure data is only fetched whenever a certain property changes. In this case its called "urls" and it is an array of URL's (TypeScript URL Type).

Here's some example code illustrating the issue:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const useCustomHook = urls => {
  const [onlyChangeWhenUrlsChange, setOnlyChangeWhenUrlsChange] = useState(
    null
  );
  useEffect(
    () => {
      setOnlyChangeWhenUrlsChange(Math.random());
    },
    [urls]
  );
  return onlyChangeWhenUrlsChange;
};

const dynamicUrls = (pageRouteParamId, someDynamicUrlParam) => {
  return [
    {
      pageRouteParamId: 1337,
      urls: [new URL(`https://someurl.com/api?id=${someDynamicUrlParam}`)]
    }
  ];
};

const SomePage: React.SFC<any> = ({
  simulateFrequentUpdatingData,
  pageRouteParamId
}) => {
  const someOtherId = 1;
  // As suggested in SO answer, using useMemo seems to work, but will that not create a memory leak?
  // Is there any good alternative?
  // const urls = useMemo(() => dynamicUrls(pageRouteParamId, someOtherId).find(url => url.pageRouteParamId === pageRouteParamId).urls, [pageRouteParamId, someOtherId]);
  const urls = dynamicUrls(pageRouteParamId, 1).find(
    url => url.pageRouteParamId === 1337
  ).urls;
  return (
    <div>
      <p>parent</p>
      <p>{simulateFrequentUpdatingData}</p>
      <p>
        Page route param id (in real app this would come from react-router route
        param): {pageRouteParamId}
      </p>
      {urls && urls.length && <MyStateLessFunctionalComponent {...{ urls }} />}
      <p>
        Page route param id (in real app this would come from react-router route
        param): {pageRouteParamId}
      </p>
      {urls && urls.length && (
        <MyStateLessFunctionalComponentWithHook {...{ urls }} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const MyStateLessFunctionalComponent: React.SFC<any> = ({ urls }) => {
  const [onlyChangeWhenUrlsChange, setOnlyChangeWhenUrlsChange] = useState(
    null
  );
  useEffect(
    () => {
      setOnlyChangeWhenUrlsChange(Math.random());
    },
    [urls]
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <p>MyStateLessFunctionalComponent</p>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(urls)}</p>
      <p>This should only change when urls change {onlyChangeWhenUrlsChange}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const MyStateLessFunctionalComponentWithHook: React.SFC<any> = ({ urls }) => {
  const onlyChangeWhenUrlsChange = useCustomHook(urls);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>MyStateLessFunctionalComponentWithHook</p>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(urls)}</p>
      <p>This should only change when urls change {onlyChangeWhenUrlsChange}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [
    simulateFrequentUpdatingData,
    setSimulateFrequentUpdatingData
  ] = useState(null);
  const [pageRouteParamId, setPageRouteParamId] = useState(1337);
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => setSimulateFrequentUpdatingData(Math.random()), 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SomePage {...{ simulateFrequentUpdatingData, pageRouteParamId }} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**Edit:**

*I had to change the title and question, since while reproducing it with the example code I realized the problem was not about "Skipping Effects inside a custom hook". Before I though I saw a difference when using useEffect directly vs inside a custom hook, and as the comments rightfully mentioned, there should not be any difference - and I came to the same conclusion while reproducing my issue with this sample code:*

You can check out a [live example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pw30xq84xm?fontsize=14).

As it was suggested in the answer below, it seems like useMemo solves the issue (see line 36)

Comment: Interesting. It should work the same with or without a custom hook. Do you think you could create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)?

Comment: yeah, it should behave the same way regardless of it being a custom hook. What does your `urls` prop look like? It rerenders multiple times even if the prop is static?

Comment: I will make a running snippet when i get back to my computer.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/pw30xq84xm?fontsize=14 (notice line 36) - unfortunately I jumped to the wrong conclusion, and it was indeed also a problem both when using useEffect directly and through another hook. I guess I will need to edit the title and question :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `urls` is being declared inside a render higher up the tree, and thus getting a new identity every time. You can either `useMemo` on the place where it is being declared, `JSON.stringify` the `urls` in the deps-array, or a `useRef` which works as an additional guard against re-runs.

Edit: This is being discussed by smarter people than me: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14476#issuecomment-471199055.

Comment: Urls is generated from a function in the parent component (Also stateless, so yes in render). But it works if i use useEffect directly in the child, MyStateLessFunctionalComponent. Why the difference?

Comment: I'm a bit embassed to admit it, but your guess was spot on. Unfortunately I jumped to the wrong conclusion when creating this post. Not sure if I should approve your answer and edit the post to fit the useMemo answer, or just nuke the question instead. About useMemo, I believe its a slippery slope to start using that, but in my example where the urls are dynamic based on some id which is unique for the specific page/route, is there any other way, other than using memo and potentially creating memory leaks? Live example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/pw30xq84xm?fontsize=14  (notice line 36)

Comment: I don't think there is a risk for memory leaks with `useMemo`, I'm pretty sure that it only saves the last memoized value in memory. Any old value should get garbage collected. 

However this concerns me: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo "Write your code so that it still works without useMemo — and then add it to optimize performance.", however Dan Abramov uses it in the issue I linked in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Read the same line, and had the same worries. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If `urls` is an array of strings you can pass that as the second argument to useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
  loadData();
}, urls);
```

that way it will check the string values instead of the array reference.

Comment: It is an array of URLs (Typescript URL type).